# Struggles to connect to network when using WPA with a BCM43225

Tags: 11.10, wireless, broadcom

When booting my laptop, it will try to connect to my wireless network, however a window keeps popping up asking me for my security password, which has already been saved.

I have to keep deleting my network settings, and reconnecting, otherwise it keeps failing to connect.

My wireless is set up with a WPA, I do not want to lower my security because of this, but it is a pain and can take me 15mins plus to finally connect.

The problem has only become apparent since a fresh install of 11.10.

IPV6 disabled.

System info:

01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM57780 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe (rev 01)

```
Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 036d

Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 43

Memory at b3400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]

Capabilities: <access denied>

Kernel driver in use: tg3

Kernel modules: tg3
```

02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43225 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)

```
Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation Device 04da

Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17

Memory at b2400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]

Capabilities: <access denied>

Kernel driver in use: brcmsmac

Kernel modules: wl, brcmsmac
```

ADDITIONAL:

In terminal I get this:

pst007x@pst007x-ubuntu64:~$ nm-applet start
** Message: applet now removed from the notification area
** (nm-applet:2816): DEBUG: old state indicates that this was not a disconnect 0
** Message: using fallback from indicator to GtkStatusIcon
** Message: applet now embedded in the notification area
** Message: No keyring secrets found for Auto Access 01/802-11-wireless-security; asking user.
** (nm-applet:2816): DEBUG: foo_client_state_changed_cb

Note this line:

** Message: No keyring secrets found for Auto Access 01/802-11-wireless-security; asking user.

At this point is where I am asked for the password.

Please report WPA issues with Ubuntu 11.10 here: 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/892727

Comment: See my [answer][1] to a similar question.


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/75929/how-can-i-stop-gnome-3-from-asking-my-wireless-password-multiple-times/76277#76277

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled all drivers and references to the BCM4*** first and only added one driver that referred to the BCM43225. Rebooted and it all works fine without any issue.

Answer (score 1):

I tried un-installing; Unity, Compiz, and ubuntu-desktop (I am using the Gnome3 shell). I think there is a problem, at times, between Unity and Gnome3... I could be wrong on that though.. mmmm :-I Anyway, seemed to work, but after a couple of reboots, the same thing happened. Going to try a fresh install.... again :-(

Comment: The Desktop manager rarely affects the actual kernel/drivers

Comment: When starting nm-applet in terminal, I get this line when I am asked for the password:............. ** Message: No keyring secrets found for Auto Access 01/802-11-wireless-security; asking user.

Comment: As though the password is not being stored correctly

Comment: I find by running: 'gnome-keyring-daemon' in terminal, the password is accepted after asking only once. Not sure what is happening here....