# How can I stop GNOME 3 from asking my wireless password multiple times?

Tags: 11.10, wireless, gnome

When I login to my account the system ask me for my wifi password in a prompt that looks like the main ubuntu screen and later again with the gnome 3 look and maybe 2 or 3 more times, sometimes the third time it connects and some it dont. I'm lost.

Answer (score 2):

I will assume you're running Network Manager. Right Click on the Network Manager symbol (in the top row on your screen. On my system, it is just Left of my speaker symbol), scroll down to "Edit Connections". A popup will open. Click on the  "Wireless tab". "Add" or "Edit" a connection, and fill in your information in all of the tabs.

To find out what's happening, here's what I would do:

1. Do nothing, until the password prompt pops up again.
2. Deal with the password prompt.
3. Do `ls -lrt /var/log` to get a list of recently modified log files.
4. Look at the last several lines of each recently modified log file. Either post the messages here, or figure out what they mean on your own.

Possibly the wireless AP you're connecting to is getting reset somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the password from the applet menu will not work. Even I faced the same problem (while using Ubuntu 12.04 with Gnome3) until I set it by accessing the Network Manager directly and entering the password.

Follow these steps:

1. Open Network from Settings.
2. Click on the Wireless tab and switch to the network you're facing problems with in the dropdown box.
3. Click on Option, go to the Wireless Security tab and then enter your password.
4. Close the window to save your settings.

It should remember your password from now on. I think this must be a problem with Gnome3 not integrating well with Ubuntu.